# Not able to implement authenticate method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am not able to make a user login in Laravel. I am using `username` instead of `email`.

Below is my Routes

```
use App\Message;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
//


Route::post('/contact','MessageController@store');

Route::get('/admin9419/dashboard','AdminDashboardController@index')->name('dash');
Route::get('/admin9419/login','SessionsController@create')->name('home');
Route::post('/admin9419/login','SessionsController@store');
Route::post('/admin9419/logout','SessionsController@destroy');
```

This is my SessionController File

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{



    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('guest');

    }


    public function create(){


        return view('sessions.create');


    }


    public function destroy(){

        auth()->logout();

        return redirect()->home();

    }

    public function store(){



       if(!auth()->attempt(['username'=>request('username'),'password'=>request('password')])){

           return back();

       }

       return redirect('/admin9419/dashboard');


    }

}
```

Error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
```

User class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Can anyone help what i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems correct.

See the Class User that it should be something like:

```
 use App\Notifications\MailResetPasswordToken;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    ....
}
```

So can you paste the User class?

Comment: I have edited my post, i tried your code and it work, can you post me a Class user?
Is class User extends Authenticatable?

Comment: added the user class file

Comment: Yes, try with user extends Authenticatable Luke in my answer

Answer (score 0):

By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

From : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

Comment: that didn't help me still getting same error if you want to look into some other files let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request){

  $username= $request->input('username');
  $password= $request->input('password');

  if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['username' => $username , 'password'=> $password ])) {
         return redirect()->intended('/admin9419/dashboard');
  }
  else{
   return redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

Comment: add use AuthenticatesUsers;